# jquery hoverOut not saving html using setTimeout()?

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I'm trying to save a piece of html code, which gets applied to an element when hovering.

This overlay html is grabbed from a dom template.

When hovering out, I want to save the overlay html for the current element using `setTimeout()` after a `fadeOut()`.

I do this because I want to maintain a specific effect, where the overlay html disappears instantly (`html('')`), but the overlay wrapper needs to `fadeOut()`.

For some reason, the `setTimeout()` won't save the html when hovering out.

My hover event (see the **hover callback**):

```
$('.isotope-item').hover(
function()
{
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var img = $(this).attr('data-img');

    var htmlIsoHover = htmlIsoHoverTemplate.replace('{id}', id);
    htmlIsoHover = htmlIsoHover.replace('{image}', img);


    var thisHtmlIsoHover = $(this).find('.hover-overlay').html();

    if (thisHtmlIsoHover.length > 0)
    {
        htmlIsoHover = thisHtmlIsoHover;
    }

    $(this).find('.hover-overlay').html(htmlIsoHover).stop(1, 1).fadeIn('fast');

},
function()
{
    var htmlIsoHover = $(this).find('.hover-overlay').html();
    $(this).find('.hover-overlay').html('').fadeOut(500);


    // this won't save

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $(this).find('.hover-overlay').html(htmlIsoHover);
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `this`, in the callback you pass to `setTimeout`, isn't your element but `window`.

You can fix it like this :

```
function()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    var htmlIsoHover = $this.find('.hover-overlay').html();
    $this.find('.hover-overlay').html('').fadeOut(500);

    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $this.find('.hover-overlay').html(htmlIsoHover);
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: That makes total sense, now that I see your solution. :) Thanks for the very fast response! I need to wait 10 mins to mark your answer.